# Element.animation typescript - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation

What is the typescript type for Element.animation? If I have code that looks like this:

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>( null );

useEffect( () => {
    const animation: ANIMTATION_TYPE = ref.current.animate( SOME_ANIMATION );
}, []);

return (
    <div ref={ref}>
        Some Div
    </div>
)
```

What should ANIMATION_TYPE be? I tried AnimationTimeline but that dosen't include the .play or .pause functions.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just `Animation`. But TS has inference, you don't have to explicitly type everything. I am wondering though how that even compiles since you're accessing a property on a reference that could be null.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the call to `animate(` in your IDE, it should tell you the type. I get this:

```
(method) Animatable.animate(
  keyframes: Keyframe[] | PropertyIndexedKeyframes | null,
  options?: number | KeyframeAnimationOptions | undefined
): Animation
```

So the return type of that method is `Animation`.

Which has a `play()` method and works like you expect.

```
const animation: Animation = document.getElementById('testing123')!.animate([])
animation.play() // works
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhmAlgWzlR4BcMCCTXrgwC8MAJiMAK7ICmYUAdAOa1QCiANrXQwEIBPAJJkAFAHIotaIjDMAjACYAzOICUAQkYIUaWqIDaAXTUAoHQQxhGAB05wBotUA)

---

You probably don't need to though. TS knows the return type of that method, and if you just want to use the values in that scope, this would do fine:

```
const animation = document.getElementById('testing123')!.animate([])
animation.play() // works
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhmAlgWzlR4YF4YBMTACuyApmFAHQDmJUAogDYmnkBCAngJK4AUA5FBLREYKgEYATAGY+ASgCEFBCjQkeAbQC6sgFDLU6cBQAODOOx6ygA)

Answer (score 0):

The animation would be of Animation type.
Here you can find what you need on the animate function.

https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.animatable.html